# How to make parent's border cover its child border?

Tags: html, css

I need help with my CSS problem. I have a parent div element and its child div. both have a border with the same size but different colors. what I want to achieve is the parent's border cover its children.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" />
</div>
```

my css

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

with the above CSS, the green border of the child is still visible. I've tried to give parent `padding: -1px` hoping it will hide the border, but no luck. How to achieve it?  or is it impossible?

Comment: Negative padding is not a thing. Negative margins are however. (But with that, you would still need to involve z-index, otherwise the child border will be _over_ the parent border.) What do you actually want to _achieve_ here? Sounds like simply giving the child a `border-right` _only_ might already suffice …?

Comment: do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/6Xg4Knp

Comment: will it be okay for you if you do this? - `border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0; border-left: 0;` to `.child` class

Answer (score 3):

Use outline instead of border:

```css
.parent {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant do that. The child is fixed component with border instead of outline